# How to put questions and answers in quiz apps

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say i have in SQL database table with:

```
QUESTION - VARCHAR[100]
OPTa - VARCHAR[40]
OPTb - VARCHAR[40]
OPTc - VARCHAR[40]
```

One of options is a good answer for a question.
What is the best way to tell which one is correct.
At the moment I added additional columnn - which holds proper answer for question:

```
ANSWER - VARCHAR[40]
```

and i'm comparing two variables.

But I think there's a better way, which I don't see at the moment.

Comment: What is the criteria for a good answer ?

Comment: @LyubomirDimov I think he mean a `Correct answer` and something was lost in translation.

Answer (score 1):

You can have two tables :

```
QuizQuestion
--------------
QuestionId | Question

QuestionOption
---------------
QuestOptionId | Option | CorrectFlg | QuestionId
```

Change above table structure as per your requirement.

Comment: Another option is have a `CorrectAnswer` table instead of a `CorrectFlg`

Comment: Table design can change as per system requirement